# Documentum groups and subgroups lost when build is performed

Tags: documentum, documentum6.5, dfc

Here's our dev process.  We have a dev Documentum environment where we make our changes, and then import those DFC changes into our docbase using Documentum Composer.

When the build is performed, we are able to deploy it successfully.  However, we find that we consistently lose our custom groups and subgroups (part of user management).  The groups exist, however we have to manually add the subgroups to the groups using Documentum Administrator.  This is an annoying post-step that we would like to remove.

Does anyone have any ideas of where to look to find the root cause?

Thanks

Comment: What is the Eclipse-based tool? Documentum Composer or your homegrown tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I checked, you can't define group memberships in a docapp, you can only define the groups themselves.

When we deploy something like that, we run an API script after we import the .dar file to define the memberships.

So it's a two-step process, but a mechanical, repeatable one.